# Sci-fi book about a boy who develops powers and bends a large coin between two fingers

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back in the early 80s, I came across a book where a pre-teen or teen boy began to develop powers. For the life of me, I cannot remember the title. It was definitely published prior to 1985...I never checked.

The only thing that I can remember is a scene in which he bends a silver dollar (or other large coin) between two fingers and thumb and another in which it describes how a broken tooth of his healed.